# Really confusing javascript quiz about 'new' and 'this' operator

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 0;
function foo() {
    x++;
    this.x = x;
    return foo;
}
var bar = new new foo;
console.log(bar.x);
```

What is logged  in the console?

I am preparing javascript job interview and came across a quiz [here](http://davidshariff.com/js-quiz/#q=13).

It is confusing...

**Can you help me explain what is going on?**

Comment: What parts don't you understand? You'll probably want to find out what happens when your `return` from a constructor call.

Comment: You can *literally* copy and paste this in the console to find out "What is logged in the console?"

Answer (score 1):

If you copy this into your console, it with log `undefined`. Why is this?

**The constructor function returns itself, the constructor function**

This means that you can write `new` in front of `foo` as many times as you want, and it will never return an instance of `foo`.

**The constructor function iterates `x`**

However, every time the constructor function is called, even without `new`, it will iterate the external `x` variable. So, if you access `x` outside of this function, it will be iterated to the number of times the `foo` function has been called.

**`new` can call a constructor function without parentheses**

Writing `new foo` automatically calls `foo` with no arguments, as if the code was `new foo()`

**The constructor function does not have an `x` property**

When the `console.log` statement looks up the `x` property of `bar`, it is really looking for one on the `foo` function-object. That property does not exist on `foo`, so the result is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Returning foo should return the object, not the value within it, nor a call from it.
2. CareerCups should have some JavaScript. You can also look at CodeWars to practice what you learn and learn how ninjas do their JavaScript code.

Comment: Doesnt it return the function itself as a string representation? "function foo() ..."

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik no. It returns the function as a function object.